# Time series: sample vs. population + population vs. realizations of random process

Tags: time-series, econometrics, sample, population

Suppose we have $120$ monthly observations (Jan 2000 - Dec 2009) of unemployment rate and suppose we would like to use these in order understand the unknown underlying stochastic process that generated these, and use that knowledge to forecast the unemployment rate on the 121st month (Jan 2010).

Does our sample of $120$ observations constitute a sample? If so, in what sense, and how is it different than the concept of sample in cross sections? How do we think of "the population" with regards to time series? How do we reconcile the concepts of population and realizations of a random process?

Comment: did you find the answer to your question ?